# Does internet speed mean per device or per modem?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, bandwidth, speedtest

When my ISP says my internet speed is 50mbps, does that mean each device I have in my household can receive up to 50mbps at once, or does that mean the sum total all the devices is up to 50mbps?

Also will one device using the internet intensively affect the internet speed test results of another device run at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When my ISP says my internet speed is 50mbps, does that mean each
> device I have in my household can receive up to 50mbps at once, or
> does that mean the sum total all the devices is up to 50mbps?

It is a combination of all devices used on the same network

> will one device using the internet intensively affect the internet
> speed test results of another device run at the same time?

This generally depends on amount of the data that is being used and what direction the data is going in (up or down), but, yes is the answer.

> ## What internet speed do I need?
>
> - Most families can get away with a cheap 20 x 5 package (20 Mbps    download speed and 5 Mbps upload speed). This allows you to surf the
>   web and stream video with 20-Mbps download speeds or back up your
>   content to the cloud with 5-Mbps upload speeds.
> - Netflix says you need 10 Mbps to stream full HD content and 25 Mbps    for 4K Ultra HD content, but you'll want faster speeds if you plan to
>   connect several devices at once. The same holds true for other
>   streaming services and game streaming services like Twitch.
> - If you're planning to stream 4K video content and have multiple    devices connecting to your network simultaneously, seriously consider
>   investing in faster download speeds, like 200 Mbps, which should work
>   for most users.
> - Use tools like [Fast.com](https://fast.com/) or [Google search Speedtest](https://www.google.com/search?q=Speedtest&oq=Speedtest&aqs) to check your internet    connection speed and determine whether you're
>   really getting the    bandwidth you're paying for.

[Source](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/internet-speed-what-you-need,news-24289.html)

Answer (score 0):

ISP speed is sum of all the devices speed. If total speed is 100mbps then by using 2 same device on same frequency will receive exactly half of total.
Personally I had used network very intensive at 40-45 mbps out of 50 mbps and same time my friend on same network didn’t face any difference.